# Boolean operator ||

Tags: javascript, syntax, boolean

I recently had to deal with some javascript and came across this code:

```
name: function(arg){
            //...
            var arg = arg || new Object();
            //...
}
```

TBH, I'm not quite fit in js, but as far as I know, this means that if `arg` is not defined, `arg` will be `new Object();`
My question now is, how does js know that this isn't considered a boolean interpretation? Or how excatly does this comparison work?

Like, javascript does have dynamic data types, so I would have assumed if `arg` was a boolean, (and if I'm not wrong, the boolean value of `new Object();` is always true) `arg` would be true after running the function, no matter the previous value of `arg` was.
However, I tested that, using various parameters (and again, I'm new to js) and the results are quite strange to me:

Using:

```
function name(arg) {
    var arg = arg || new Object();
    return arg;
}
```

Results:

```
name() = [object Object]
name(1) = 1
name(true) = true
name(false) = [object Object]
name('true') = true
name('false') = false
name(null) = [object Object]
```

I would have expected these results, except for `name(false) = [object Object]`. What's the reason for that result? I couldn't really find a satisfying answer.

Regards,
Simon

Comment: `name (false)` passes `false` (boolean) as a parameter. However, this kind of OR that you setted up can be also seen as a sort of "if" statement, which works like: "if `exp1` is false, then `exp2`". Therefore, passing false as the first parameters executes `exp2`, which is your object. when you pass 'false', instead, you're passing a string, which is an object, therefore it will evaluate to TRUE and won't execute exp2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...this means that if `arg` is not defined, `arg` will be `new Object()`;

Not quite: It means that if `arg` has a *falsey* value, then assign `new Object()` to `arg`.

The `||` operator works like this: It evaluates the left-hand operand and if that value is *truthy*, the result of the operation is that value; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand operand and results in that value.

So what are "falsey" and "truthy"? Falsey values are `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`. Truthy values are all others.

More in [this article](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) on my blog.

The `&&` operator is similarly powerful, in a somewhat converse way: It evalutes the left-hand operand and if that value is *falsey*, the result of the operation is that value; otherwise it evalutes the right-hand operand and the result is that value. So `a = b && b.foo;` will assign `a` the value of `b` if it's falsey (`null`, `undefined`, etc.) or the value of `b.foo` if not.

> My question now is, how does js know that this isn't considered a boolean interpretation?

Because that's how it's defined in the specification. JavaScript's `||` and `&&` are different from, say, Java's which always result in a boolean. It's by design, and very powerful.